# How to unsnap/ detach the pivot point from the 3d cursor

Tags: interface, snapping, origin, 3d-cursor

I have tried to search up on this but none of the tutorial I find helps on my situation. The solution I have tried: options in the “Set origin” and options in the “Snap” in the object panel.

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EZlcITSuZ-tDiLCIeJeu5WIB-aG415RlPYlEra92ML-9nQ?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=xxSgBL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the 3D cursor selected in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel, switch to *Median Point*:

[image]